# DataBinding inside a ContentTemplate inside a Style in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding, styles

I'm defining the following style in XAML:

```
 <Style TargetType="telerik:RadDiagramShape" x:Key="styleShapeBase">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="120" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="60" />
    <Setter Property="IsResizingEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock x:Name="lblName" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then in the code-behind I'm **assigning the data context**. I want to draw a shape with some text in it that comes from an object (if this end up working I'm going to put more info there). I'm doing it like this:

```
var shape = new RadDiagramShape();
shape.Style = (Style)Resources["styleShapeBase"];
shape.DataContext = item.DataContext;
```

Where `item` is a simple POCO that has a `Name` property of type `string` (this part works, I've traced it, i.e. the DataContext is correctly assigned).

But the **data binding** never occurs. Is it by design (i.e. no data binding inside a content template), if not what's wrong? Thanks,

Comment: Try using TemplateBinding instead. Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877047/silverlight-templatebinding-a-rectangle

Comment: TemplateBinding only works in the body of a Control Template, so is not relevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Bindings in your DataTemplates. In this case, the Binding will look for a Name property on whatever you set as the Content of your RadDiagramShape.

You should ensure that your class has this property and that it is a string.

If that still doesn't work, can you post details of how you set the style and Content of each instance of RadDiagramShape, and of the object you are trying to bind to?

---

Somewhere in the Control Template for the RadDiagramShape class, there will be a ContentPresenter with its ContentTemplate bound to the one you have defined. The problem is that the ContentTemplate is only used if the Content property is also set. Otherwise nothing will be loaded into that ContentPresenter.

To make this work, you must set the Content property on the instance of this element.

[This is a good place to start understanding what the DataContext property is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: OK, so I don't even have to set the DataContext property? It is implicit when setting the Content?

Comment: You do not have to set DataContext unless you want to define Content through Data Binding. Content must always be set.

Comment: "To make this work, you must set the Content property on the instance of this element." -- Thanks a lot for pointing this out, this totally solves the problem. I should know this already, but nonetheless I couldn't see this problem by just looking at my code.